# pass value through custom attribute for method access

Tags: c#

Can any one please tell me about custom attribute for method.I need to pass a string to attribute.If the string is true then i will access the method otherwise don't access the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure, if I understood your question wrongly. But are you talking about following kind of attribute which decorates the method. I had created this code when I was exploring attributes. I am pasting it here. Hope it helps.

In this, I have created the attribute,  [Allow("Valid")] if it is valid we can call the method , else not.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{

  using System;
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All)]
public class AllowAttribute : System.Attribute 
{
   public readonly string SomeString;

   public AllowAttribute(string someString)  // your string is passed in custom attribute 
   {
      this.SomeString = someString;
   }


}
public interface IAllowAttributeInvoker
{
  object AllowAttributeInvokeMethod<T>(string methodName, T classInstance, object[] parametersArray);

}

public  class AllowAttributeInvoker: IAllowAttributeInvoker
{
  public object AllowAttributeInvokeMethod<T>(string methodName, T classInstance, object[] parametersArray)
  {
    System.Reflection.MemberInfo info = typeof(T).GetMethod(methodName);
    if (IsAttributeValid(info))
    {
      var method = (typeof (T)).GetMethod(methodName);
      Console.WriteLine("Invoking method");
      var result = method.Invoke(classInstance, parametersArray);

      return result;
    }
    else
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Can not invoke this method.");
    }
    return null;
  }


  private static bool IsAttributeValid(MemberInfo member)
   {
        foreach (object attribute in member.GetCustomAttributes(true))
        {
            if (attribute is AllowAttribute && ((AllowAttribute)attribute).SomeString == "Valid")
            {
               return true;
            }
        }
      return false;
   }
}


  public class EmployeeService :AllowAttributeInvoker
  {

    public object PaySalary()
    {
      return AllowAttributeInvokeMethod("PaySalaryInvoke", this, null);
    }

    [Allow("Valid")]
    public void PaySalaryInvoke()
    {

      Console.WriteLine("Salary Paid.");
    }
  }

  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Console.ReadLine();

      EmployeeService service = new EmployeeService();
      service.PaySalary();
      Console.ReadLine();

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable response Ganesh

Comment: You are welcome. Please vote up if answer helps you, that serves better to community.

Comment: Ganesh can u tell me the same thing in xml attribute...Just xml attribute read the method.If the method is true when compared with given string it allow to the method otherwise it won't.

Comment: Hi friends,

      
      I need to do custom attribute by using Boolean values.Below i have given the sample for  

      example.Please consider that one and help me for better custom attribute code.

    


 

     I have 3 string variable...names as A,B,C.



     [Custom attribute,if(A=true)]// it enter into the method at the time of calling the method.

     [Custom attribute,if(B=false)]//it terminate 
 
     [Custom attribute,if(C=true)]// same as A to enter int to the method.

     public void  _somemethod()
 
     {
 

     // some code
     
     }

Comment: Hai Ganesh Thank you very much.You gave me very useful code to me.Thanks once again.

Comment: Hai ganesh i have one more doubt.In the method i have 1 or more parameter.But the invoke is giving as null.How to solve for parameter count mismatch.

Comment: Can you please post the exact code where you are facing the issue.

Comment: your code only.What happen mean.I had pass some parameter through the method.public void PaySalaryInvoke(string A or int B or byte C).  return AllowAttributeInvokeMethod("PaySalaryInvoke", this, null); here is null for that.

Comment: Please tell me how to pass the parameter.

Comment: You can pass object[] array instead of null. MethodInfo someMethod = someclasstype.GetMethod("SomeMethod");
        object magicValue = someMethod.Invoke(someClassObject, new object[]{500});
 Here 500 is sent as a parameter to SomeMethod method of someclass

Comment: Hi ganesh its working.But i have nearly 10 methods with having parameter signature is not same...i.e Method1(string a,int b)and Method2(int a,int b,ulong c) and Method3().......What the problem is new object[3] mean it take only 3 arguments...others are showing parameter mismatch.

Comment: Hi ganesh i have one more doubt..I am using two attribute on same type..like [Allow("Valid1")][Allow("Valid2")] on the above method.What happen was its directly going to second attribute [Allow("Valid2")].

Comment: Please give me suggestion

Answer (score 0):

1-You can define public user access list:

```
public List<string> AccessRules = new List<string>();
```

2-Set user access rules in constructor :

```
AccessRules.AddRange(new[] { "GetCurrentDateTime", "GetCurrentDate" });
```

3-In secure methods check user access rule

```
public DateTime GetCurrentDateTime()
{
   bool haveAccess = AccessRules.Any(c => c == "GetCurrentDateTime");
   if (haveAccess)
   {
      return DateTime.Now;
   }
   return null;
}
```

Comment: Hi friends,



     I need help for doing custom attribute in c#.


 

 I have 3 string variable...names as A,B,C.



 [Custom attribute,if(A=true)]// it enter into the method at the time of calling the method.
 [custom attribute,if(B=false)]//it terminate 
 [custom attribute,if(C=true)]// same as A to enter int to the method.
 public _somemethod()
 {
 // some code
 }